# Javascript DOM setAttribute not working inside a function call

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an HTML file with an input element to which I wish to add a new attribute, named "valid-fieldset011", which is used as a link to an AngularJS validator. The input element has the attribute id="fieldset011".  If I use the following script (enclosed in script tags)

```
var inputElement = document.getElementById('fieldset011');
inputElement.setAttribute('valid-fieldset011', '');
```

everything works fine.  The validator recognizes the new attribute.  However, if I add the attribute onfocus="theFunction()" and invoke the following script (also enclosed in script tags)

```
function theFunction() {

  var inputElement = document.getElementById('fieldset011');
  inputElement.setAttribute('valid-fieldset011', '');
  console.log("in theFunction");

}
```

by clicking on the input element, it doesn't work.  In this case the validator is not recognizing the new attribute.  But I know the function is being executed because the message "in theFunction" appears in the browser console.

Would anyone know why this is happening?  I want to use the function as I want to be able to feed in the element id as a parameter.

Comment: I very strongly suspect that the `.setAttribute()` call *does* work. You could confirm that by adding `console.log("in theFunction: ", inputElement);`.

Comment: most likely, since you are using Angular, it adds the attribute, but then Angular has some reason to update, and recreates the element (and the new one doesn't have that attribute) - basically if you're using Angular, you should do it the Angular way, modifying the DOM outside of Angular is going to cause issues

Comment: AngularJS doesn't monitor changes to the DOM like that. You've have to kick off another digest cycle (using something like `$scope.digest()`), but it sounds like you're working against AngularJS for some reason.

Comment: Thanks to everyone for their replies.

Pointy: You are correct.  The attribute is being created.  Only the Angular validator is not seeing it.

dave: Could you explain what you mean by "the Angular way"?  I have not found any Angular commands for creating DOM elements.   Also, please note that I'm using AngularJS and not one of the later versions.

Heretic Monkey: How/where would I use $scope.digest()?   Should it somehow go into the validator script (not included here due to space restrictions).

Comment: Hello again, I'm still hoping that someone can help with this.  The comments above have not been helpful (too brief or vague).  Thanks.